# EJS in rails production not compiling properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ejs, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I have a rails app that uses EJS templates. It is running perfectly on development, but in production, it acts like the EJS processing step is skipped, as my JST hash contains the exact EJS file contents. Each file has  .jst.ejs extension and I have gem 'ejs' in my Gemfile. How can I make sure precompile on production is actually executing the EJS step?

Comment: EJS is for Javascript how exactly are you using it in your Rails app ?

Comment: Single page web app using backbone and underscore templates. See http://www.bigjason.com/blog/precompiled-javascript-templates-rails-3-1